# Why is meshgrid useful? Particularly, why are coordinate matrices valuable over other representations (like simple arrays)?

Tags: numpy

As I understand it, this is the basic usage of np.meshgrid:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = xx * yy
plt.contourf(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

Where `xx` is:

```
[[0.   0.25 0.5  0.75 1.  ]
 [0.   0.25 0.5  0.75 1.  ]
 [0.   0.25 0.5  0.75 1.  ]
 [0.   0.25 0.5  0.75 1.  ]
 [0.   0.25 0.5  0.75 1.  ]]
```

And `yy` is the transpose (in this case, at least).

What is not clear to me is *why* we need two separate 5x5 arrays.  For example, why not use a 25x2 representation:

```
[[ 0.  , 0.  ],
 [ 0.  , 0.25],
 [ 0.  , 0.5 ],
... (etc)
```

Or even a 5x5x2 array.

Is there any clear advantage to using coordinate matrices?  Linear algebra is a weak spot for me, so it's entire possible I'm missing something here.

---

**Edit:**
I disagree with the duplicate tag.  My question was more, "why is the output this strange format?", as opposed to "why would I want a meshgrid in the first place?"

With that said, I think Paul's comment mostly answers my question: In particular, the coordinate matrices make for cleaner vectorized operations when computing some `z = f(x, y)`.

Comment: Doesn't your example answer your question? For typical ways of working on the coordinates it is most convenient having them as arrays x and y because then as long as your operations are vectorized any code originally made for a single x and a single y will work unchanged (in theory).

Comment: Okay, I think I get it.  For more "mathy" functions like f(x, y), it definitely makes sense to keep them separate.  For other applications (like a classifier), it seems like a clean way to create that 25x2 grid after calling ravel().

Comment: `meshgrid` gives a perfectly good example using `plt.contour`.  It's easy to convert the tuple of (5,5) arrays into a (5,5,2), or the (25,2).  `np.mgrid` can be used to make a (2,5,5) array.  `meshgrid` itself provides a couple of variants.